# onPress on picker.item to close the dropdown- react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, picker

I have a dropdown and I'm using react-native picker component. Everything is working fine, the problem is that I need to close the dropdown when the user presses on any picker items

```
        this.state.list.map((obj, index) => {
           return (
            <Picker.Item key={index} label={obj.label} value={obj.value} />
          );
```

the picker gives us only onValueChange prop, but I need onPress functionality for any picker items individually to close the dropdown.

I have also tried this

```
          this.state.list.map((obj, index) => {
          return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.itemPressHandler}>
                <Picker.Item key={index} label={obj.label} value={obj.value} />
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

          );
```

but it doesn't render the dropdown.

Is there any way to get this functionality?

Comment: Are you wrapping picker-item inside picker like this  <Picker mode={'dialog'}><Picker.Item /></Picker>?

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker).

```
<Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.valueSelected}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
         this.handlePickerValueChange(itemValue, itemIndex)
    }
    mode={'dialog'} // optional
>
    this.state.list.map((obj, index) => {
       return (
        <Picker.Item key={index} label={obj.label} value={obj.value} />
      );
    });
</Picker>
```

Set the default selected value in state

```
state={
    valueSelected: "Choose a value"
}
```

Handle change when user selects a different option

```
handlePickerValueChange = (itemValue, itemIndex) => {
   //do your stuff
}
```